# HOC's handler function bypassed in Jest

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, higher-order-components

Can anyone help me understand why the handler function in the HOC does not get called when the `blur` event is simulated in this jest test?

```
//MyInput.js
export const MyInput = (props) => (
  <div>
    ...
    <input onBlur={ props.onBlur } />
    ...
  </div>
)


//HOC.js
export const withHOC = (SomeComponent) => {
  return (props) => {
    const handleBlur = () => {
      console.log('this does not get called');
      //do stuff
      props.onBlur();
    }

    return <SomeComponent onBlur={handleBlur} />;
  }
}

// test.js
describe('HOC', () => {
  it('fires a  callback in response to the blur event', () => {
    const ModifiedInput = withHOC(MyInput);
    const onBlurMock = jest.fn(() => {
      console.log('this does get called');
    });
    const wrapper = mount(<ModifiedInput onBlur={onBlurMock} />);
    const input = wrapper.find('input');
    input.simulate('blur');
    expect(onBlurMock).toHaveBeenCalled();
  })
})
```

Comment: your code had few syntax errors(I've fixed, you can see it through post history), but after fixing them(otherwise test did not run) I see both `console.log` printing their messages. May it be something related to specific version?

Comment: I use enzyme 3.11.0 and jest 25.5.4